# В массив записывается не то число C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

Весь код прикреплен. Суть его в том, что считывается 5тизначное число, и записывается в массив int. При вводе числа 12345 в массив записывается 49, 50, 51, 52, 53. Я уже пробовал дебажить, до записи **numstr.ElementAt(i)** (пробовал и **numstr[i]**) в **arr[i]** все нормально, **arr[0]** равно нулю, как и положено, **numstr.ElementAt(i)** равен 1, как вводилось, но после операции в 9 строке в массив записывается 49. Откуда оно взялось? Куда делась единица? Почему так получилось?

Весь код я пишу в VSCode и запускаю через .net (т. е. создаю проект командой **dotnet new console** и т.д. )

```
Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
string numstr = num.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(num);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    arr[i] = numstr.ElementAt(i);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: `numstr.ElementAt(i)` можно писать короче - `numstr[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что Вы считываете **символы** из **строки** `numstr`, а они преобразуются согласно таблице ASCII — символ '1' имеет код `49`, '2' — `50` и т.д.

Я предлагаю при занесении в массив преобразовывать получившийся символ в Int при помощи формулы `numstr.ElementAt(i) - '0'` — в таком случае от кода текущего символа отнимется '0', или `48`, и тогда всё будет передано верно.

```
Console.Write("Enter your number: ");
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
string numstr = num.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(num);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    arr[i] = numstr.ElementAt(i) - '0'; // '1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1, например
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

UPD: ещё вариант без подобных ухищрений — `int.Parse(numstr.ElementAt(i).ToString());` — он преобразует символ в строку, а затем получившуюся строку преобразует в число. Про `Parse` и его особенности можете прочесть [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/20.4.php).

Ещё один вариант — [`Char.GetNumericValue(numstr.ElementAt(i))`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=net-6.0#system-char-getnumericvalue(system-char))

Comment: Да, так можно, но это костыль получается) Нет какой-то функции, которая сконвертирует все правильно?

Comment: @l0cus да, такие функции есть, добавил в свой ответ

Comment: @l0cus для решения задачи через символы вычитание `'0'` - не костыль, а практически эталоное решение.

Comment: Уточнение: в строках CLR используется таблица символов UTF-16, а не ASCII. Она просто совпадает по кодам с ASCII в своей начальой части.

Comment: Уточнение к уточнению: используется таблица Unicode в кодировке UTF-16. Сама по себе UTF-16 таблицей символов не является.